# Java Jsoup with GoogleAPI - Error: Status 503

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to make a google search from Jsoup. But i getting the Error:

> org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503, URL=https://ipv4.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.google.com/search%253Fq%253DJ%252520%2526%252520K%252520Pumpenservice%252520Erfurt%252520Erfurt%2526num%253D1&q=EgTVmVsYGJCJucoFIhkA8aeDS70kBAG8SxBgsgwr3uhzT435x_KnMgNyY24

So how can i fix them?
I tried to make a random time for each search between 15 and 26 sec.
But it won't work.

Here's my code:

```
...
for(String s : haendler)
{
 Thread.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(15000, 26000));
 startJavaSearchGoogle(cellValueMay,street);
}
}


 public void startJavaSearchGoogle(String suche, String street) throws IOException {
         try {


            String searchURL = GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL + "?q=" + suche + " "+street + "&num=" + 1;

            System.out.println("########################################");
            System.out.println(searchURL);
            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(searchURL)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html")
                    .timeout(5000).get();

            Elements results = doc.select("h3.r > a");

            for (Element result : results) {
                String linkHref = result.attr("href");
                String linkText = result.text();
                System.out.println("Text::" + linkText + ", URL::"
                        + linkHref);
                new Screenshot().make(linkHref);
            }
            System.out.println("########################################");



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The URL from the Error code shows me the following in the browser

[image]

Comment: what's the status when you access the url from your browser?

Comment: Have EDIT my Post

Comment: So, try accessing the legitimate urls. Google is suspecting!

Comment: What do u mean exactly? Which legitimate urls ? How is the url ?

Comment: Did you read the URL? It says you have violated their terms of service, probably by making too many requests.

Comment: Ok but how can i solve that?